# Cshtml files with Gulp browser sync

Tags: asp.net, razor, gulp, browser-sync

How do I get gulp browser sync to work with MVC ASP.net? It works fine with .html files but it downloads a blank file when I use .cshtml files.

```
gulp.task("browser-sync", function () {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./",
            proxy: "localhost",
            index: "Areas/Music/Views/Songs/Index.cshtml"
        }
    });
});

gulp.task("watch", function () {
    gulp.watch(["js/*.js", "Content/*.css", "Areas/**/*.cshtml"], ["scripts", "css", "html"]);
});

gulp.task("default", ["scripts", "css", "html", "browser-sync", "watch"]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
gulp.task('watch', ['tasks', 'you', 'want', 'to', 'run'], function(){
    // sass and js watch functions
    gulp.watch('./Views/**/*.cshtml').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```

Comment: Everytime you add new `cshtml` files to your project, you need to re-run gulp watch task

Comment: You're wrong. The script above looks up the file system not the URL.